# Importing csv to R. Levels

Tags: r, csv

I've got csv file generated by Grafana, when I import it to R i have the problems with levels:

```
ssz[2,3]

[1] 919.7777777777778
3519 Levels: 1000.1746031746031 1000.2698412698413 1000.3333333333334 1000.3809523809524 1000.4603174603175 ... null
```

when I change to String as factors the integers are changed to characters.

Comment: In case my answer doesn't work for you please answer the following questions: Which reading methods do you use? What does your last sentence "when I change to String as factors the integers are changed to characters." mean?

Comment: I once wrote some things about factors, might be useful with respect to conversion: http://blog.haunschmid.name/how-to-handle-factors-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most reading methods you can set: `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Afterwards you can transform the required columns using `as.numeric(x)`

I hope this is what you want, your question is not very clear.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for response. I am not an expert.
I've tried both eariler and it doesn't work.

Comment: No problem, R is not always intuitive. Did it help you?

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it earlier, but forgot about some null values in column. Now everything is perfect.

Comment: Would be nice if you accept my answer if it helped you ;)